# Reading <span> elements with a single attribute from webpage with VB

Tags: vb.net

I have spent almost two days from the web in order to get the solution for my below request.

I need to get the list of participants name from the following web page ;

http://www.eurovent-certification.com/en/Certified_products/Access_by_programme.php?rub=04&srub=01&ssrub=&lg=en&select_prog=AHU

I have tried to marked with yellow in the below screenshot ;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IldG.png)

Would you please help me to do that in VB?

Now with the codes that i tried to get the participant list but could not do that with the loop

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim contentstr As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.eurovent-certification.com/en/Certified_products/Access_by_programme.php?rub=04&srub=01&ssrub=&lg=en&select_prog=AHU")

    Dim StartIndex As Integer = ContentStr.IndexOf("<span class=""texte"">")
    Dim StrLength As Integer = ContentStr.IndexOf(vbLf, StartIndex) - StartIndex

    textbox1.Text = contentstr.Substring(StartIndex, StrLength)

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: It's pretty simple, inside that <td> loop over <span>s and get innertext, that is if you are using a webbrowser. You didn't show any code that you have.

Comment: There's nothing special about that page. You can transfer it with any of the .Net standard objects (`HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, `HttpClient`. I'ld prefer `HttpWebRequest` with a `CookieContainer` in this case. No TLS required). The payload is `115.733` bytes, after UTF-8 encoding (the encoding is provided by the server (Apache), meaning, you don't have to derive it). The names you're after are enclosed in `<span>` elements with a single attribute: `class="texte"`. You can use a standard `HtmlDocument` object (provided by a `WebBrowser` class) to parse the Html document content.

Comment: Hi CruleD, I dont want to use webbrowser which i need to read the html code with vb programming and display the list of participant in the program. If i can do that, at the second step i will give an option to the user which they selected the participant name and click i will reflect the same at the html and get the details of each individual participants

Comment: Hi Jimi, Can you please just give me more coding example for how to parse it and create a loop to receive all the participant until the end of the page.. Sorry to asking more but i have just started programming and i believe this one where should i do after reaching advance level..

Comment: For start, you need to decide what you want to use. And you can get html for it with this Dim SourceHTML As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(YOURURL)

Comment: Hi CruleD, can you please recommend to decide which std objects to start and give me some example to create loop and get the span elements attribute. Really sorry for taking your time as a very beginner..

Comment: HTMLAgility pack is good and lots of people use it.

Comment: Yes but can you please guide me to move further, how can i get the list of participanf text with a loop

Comment: Load the string into htmlagility then select the node any way you want, you can copy the xpath. Do a for each loop over it's children to get the names. Look up a guide for it, there are many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import HtmlAgilityPack
Dim web As New HtmlWeb
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://www.eurovent-certification.com/en/Certified_products/Access_by_programme.php?rub=04&srub=01&ssrub=&lg=en&select_prog=AHU")
Dim ParticipantNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table/tr/td[2]/table[4]/tr[2]/td[2]//span[@class='texte']")
```

Now inspect ParticipantNodes with breakpoint and decide what you want to do with it.

Comment: Great, very good starting, but it is also receiving the part from here which we dont want ;  <td width="681" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e5e5e5" ><span class="texte">

    
      - If you want to apply for certification, please use <a href="mailto:apply@eurovent-certification.com" class="contenu">apply@eurovent-certification.com</a>
 <br> - If you want to correct your own data, please write to the technician in charge of your list.

Comment: Then just expand the filter, point it more precisely to the part you want or filter the results.

Comment: Really thank you...It works.. now i can move forward, can i continue from the same topic for the further question of my program or shall create a new topic if needed?

Comment: It's one question per /thread/. And Idk why someone downvoted me, I though my answer was useful.